# SQL - Remove (Eliminate) columns which have no data

Tags: sql-server, null

I wonder that;
in SQl, is it possible to not bring the columns which have no data (or zero value)?

```
Select * from PLAYER_TABLE where PLAYER_NAME='cagri'
```

it is bringing just 1 row. because there is only one player which PLAYER_NAME is "cagri".

And there are 30 columns for example statistics. 
Score-Rebound-PlayedMinutes-Fauls etc....

```
Score=2
Rebound=0
PlayedMinutes=2
Fauls=0
```

and I want to see only [Score] and [PlayedMinutes] columns when call my query.

is it possible?

Comment: use `dynamic sql` , a solution is a procedure and not a one-liner sql statement unless otherwise compressed.

Comment: So `select [Score] , [PlayedMinutes] from PLAYER_TABLE where [Score] is not null and [PlayedMinutes] is not null`?

Comment: @scsimon  .. he wants to get all columns with a value.. 30 columns in the table... if the 5 columns have values then return 5 columns

Comment: he stated he only wanted to see those two columns when "he calls his query" @maSTAShuFu ... so what does that mean?

Comment: @scsimon sorry for the missalignment, maSTAShuFu is right. I will use my query in c# and it will call it for each player with another click. I don't know which player has zero data for which column. and its changing player to player so I want to enter just player name, and all valuable (not zero) columns should come. for player_name:cagri, it will bring only [Score] and [PlayedMinute]. but for player_name:scsimon it will bring all columns, because there is data in all columns for scsimon. Please let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I would definitely handle this at the application later then, but @maSTAShuFu is on the right track if you are set on doing this at the DB level

Comment: There’s no logical difference between not selecting a column when it’s zero/blank and returning it, because by omission you know it’s blank, so logically you always know what its value is. Just always return all columns and let the application handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this logic over a `stored procedure in SQL`

DDL

```
create table usr_testtable 
(player varchar(30),col1 float, col2 float, col3 float, col4 float)

insert into usr_testtable 
values ('Jordan',10,20,3,0)
```

Convert to Stored Proc

```
declare @playername varchar(30) = 'Jordan'   --- pass this value

declare @ctr smallint = 2  -- start from ordinal 2
declare @maxctr smallint = (SELECT max(ORDINAL_POSITION)
                            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'usr_testTable')

declare @columns varchar(max) = ''
declare @columnswithvalues varchar(max) = ''

declare @coltocheck varchar(30)


declare @mysql nvarchar(max)
declare @coloutput varchar(30) 

while @ctr <= @maxctr  
    begin

            SELECT @coltocheck = COLUMN_NAME
                            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'usr_testTable'
                            and ORDINAL_POSITION = @ctr


          set @mysql = N'select @output = ' + @coltocheck + ' from usr_testTable where player =''' + @playername + ''' and cast(' + @coltocheck +' as float) > 0'

          EXECUTE sp_executesql    @mysql,N'@output int OUTPUT',@output = @coloutput OUTPUT;



          if @coloutput > 0 
             begin
              set @columns = coalesce(@columns + ',' + @coltocheck,@columns)
              set @columnswithvalues =  coalesce(@columnswithvalues + char(13) + char(10) + @coltocheck + ' : '  + @coloutput,@columnswithvalues)  --- text form
            end

          set @coloutput = ''

          set @ctr= @ctr + 1

    end

-- final result in table format

set @mysql = N'select player' + @columns + ' from usr_testTable where player =''' + @playername + ''' '
EXECUTE sp_executesql @mysql

-- final result in text format appended with columnname
select @columnswithvalues    -- format to display in text
```

Comment: I don't know how to save this as a Procedure :) But this is working like an sql query. So I will use this as an sql sentence by changing only the player_name etc.. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

First create dynamic SQL to select all columns names in the table `PLAYER_TABLE` except `PLAYER_NAME`, then unpivot data from `PLAYER_TABLE` into table `PLAYER_TABLE1`, then you can search values <> 0 and select this column in second dynamic SQL.

```
DROP TABLE PLAYER_TABLE1

DECLARE @Player NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(max); 
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @columns2 NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @sql2 NVARCHAR(max);
SET @player='cagri'
SET @columns = Stuff((SELECT ',' 
                             + Quotename(Rtrim(Ltrim(x.columns))) 
                      FROM   (SELECT COLUMN_NAME as columns FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME= 'PLAYER_TABLE' and COLUMN_NAME<>'PLAYER_NAME' ) AS x 
                      ORDER  BY X.columns 
                      FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, ''); 
SET @sql = N' SELECT 
        PLAYER_NAME, Un_Pivot.Field, Un_Pivot.Value
    INTO PLAYER_TABLE1
    FROM
        (
         SELECT * FROM PLAYER_TABLE
        ) Data
    UNPIVOT
        (
         Value FOR Field IN ('+@columns+')
        ) AS Un_Pivot'; 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;

SET @columns2 = Stuff((SELECT ',' 
                             + Quotename(Rtrim(Ltrim(y.Field))) 
                      FROM   (SELECT Field FROM PLAYER_TABLE1 WHERE VALUE<>0 AND PLAYER_NAME=@Player) AS y
                      ORDER  BY y.Field 
                      FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '');
SET @sql2 = N'SELECT PLAYER_NAME,'+@columns2+'FROM PLAYER_TABLE WHERE PLAYER_NAME='+char(39)+@Player+char(39);
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql2
```